# How to get name of variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have simple question.
How to get name of variable time from this example:

```
let x = {
  color: string = red;
}

let y = getVarName(x.color);
console.log(y);
```

> Result: color

How i can get this result above? getVarName is example function which i want to make.

Comment: I don't know if I got the question correctly, but variable names are determined by the programmer and the programmer can always log the variable name like `console.log('color');`

Comment: what is the use case of doing this ? why not simply `console.log('color')`

Answer (score 1):

The right question is How to get obj **property**'s name based on it's value. Object contain no variable, only properties.

First use [Obj.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of keys from the obj, then use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the key that match the obj property value you passed in :

```
 getPropName = (value) => x.keys().find(key => x[key] === value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question.In typescript you can do something like this if you really want to get it by a function. Else you can simply get it by `x.color`

```
  let x = {
  color : 'red',
  getColor : function(){
    return this.color
  }
}

let y = x.getColor(); 
console.log(y); // output red
```

working example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-73dpve?embed=1&file=index.ts

If you want key name than try this

```
let keys = Object.keys(x).filter(k=>x[k]==='red');

console.log(keys[0]) // output color
```

Read about `Object.keys()` from js documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Nope, i wan't output : color

Answer (score -1):

You can use below for getting output as color.

```
let color : string = 'red';
let xp : any = '';
let z = {
   colors : color,
}

let p = getVarName(z.colors);
console.log('colorname: ',p);
function getVarName(xp){
   return xp;
}
console.log('color name: ',z.colors);
let keys = Object.keys(z).filter(k=>z[k]==='red');

console.log('key: ',keys[0])
```

You can check this working example refer below link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-73dpve?embed=1&file=index.ts